# Issue accessing Facebook OAuth via Marketing API in production environment

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I'm encountering an issue while trying to access Facebook OAuth via the Marketing API in the production environment. Interestingly, I can successfully perform the access when on localhost, but I face difficulties when attempting it on the production link.

Here are some additional details:

- I am using the Facebook Business Marketing API.
- OAuth authentication works correctly when on localhost.
- When trying to access it in the production environment, I receive
  a blank page.

Another piece of information: I have three links - api.blahblahblah.com (backend), app.blahblahblah.com (frontend app), and blahblahblah.com (site).

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm having a similar issue as you.